# I want to replace value of a specific rows by calculating median of selected rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as shown below. i want to replace the values for 3Monday to 3Sunday with median.

```
|wk&day    | %dict   |
|----------|---------|
|1Friday   |    6    |
|1Monday   |    6    |
|1Saturday |    1.7  |
|1Sunday   |1.698750 |
|1Thursday |6.538169 |
|1Tuesday  |7.117872 |
|1Wednesday|6.545507 |
|2Friday   |2.3775163|
|2Monday   |2.843480 |
|2Saturday |1.918890 |
|2Sunday   |1.7391091|
|2Thursday |2.5646356|
|2Tuesday  |2.7847760|
|2Wednesday|2.7921140|
|3Friday   |2.8728322|
|3Monday   |2.7994520|
|3Saturday |2.2601081|
|3Sunday   |1.7170951|
|3Thursday |2.8581562|
|3Tuesday  |2.8838392|
|3Wednesday|2.6526918|
```

if i want to replace the value for 3Monday in the same dataframe for that i need to calculate median of 1Monday,2Monday.
3monday = median(1Monday,2Monday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#extract digit(s) starting column wk&day and names of days
df1 = df['wk&day'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)(\D+)')

#filter 1,2 rows and count median per names of days
s = df.groupby(df1.loc[df1[0].isin(['1','2']), 1])['%dict'].median()
print (s)
1
Friday       4.188758
Monday       4.421740
Saturday     1.809445
Sunday       1.718930
Thursday     4.551402
Tuesday      4.951324
Wednesday    4.668811
Name: %dict, dtype: float64

#convert wk&day to index, so possible selec by start and end position
#replace by medians
df = df.set_index('wk&day')
df.loc['3Monday':'3Sunday', '%dict'] = s.add_prefix('3')
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df.tail(7))
        wk&day     %dict
14     3Friday  2.872832
15     3Monday  4.421740
16   3Saturday  1.809445
17     3Sunday  1.718930
18   3Thursday  2.858156
19    3Tuesday  2.883839
20  3Wednesday  2.652692
```